# How can i select multiple table to datagridview?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to combine 3 table into 1 datagridview but i want some spesific columns from each table

these are my tables

**a.Malzemeler**
-Malzeme_ID (PK)
-Malzemeİsmi
-Gram_mL
-Adet
-BirimFiyat
-ToplamFiyat

**b.Tarifler**
-Tarif_ID (PK)
-Tarif_İsmi
-Talimatlar

**c.TariflerveMalzemeler**
-ID
-Tarif_ID (FK)
-Malzeme_ID (FK)
-Gram_mL
-Adet

what i want to do is

**d.Result**
-Tarif_İsmi (From table b)
-Malzeme_İsmi (from table a)
-Gram_mL(From table c)
-Adet          (from table c)
-Talimatlar (From Table b)

My select query work on SQL

```
"SELECT Tarif_İsmi,Malzemeİsmi, TariflerveMalzemeler.Gram_mL, TariflerveMalzemeler.Adet, Talimatlar FROM Malzemeler 
JOIN TariflerveMalzemeler ON Malzemeler.Malzeme_ID = TariflerveMalzemeler.Malzeme_ID JOIN Tarifler ON TariflerveMalzemeler.Tarif_ID = Tarifler.Tarif_ID"
```

but i dont know how to make it work on datagridview ?

Comment: Start from here [ADO.NET Tutorial For Beginners and Professionals](https://dotnettutorials.net/course/ado-net-tutorial-for-beginners-and-professionals/)

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication166
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable Malzemeler = new DataTable();
            Malzemeler.Columns.Add("Malzeme_ID", typeof(string));
            Malzemeler.Columns.Add("Malzemeİsmi", typeof(string));
            Malzemeler.Columns.Add("Gram_mL", typeof(string));
            Malzemeler.Columns.Add("Adet", typeof(string));
            Malzemeler.Columns.Add("BirimFiyat", typeof(string));
            Malzemeler.Columns.Add("ToplamFiyat", typeof(string));

            DataTable Tarifler = new DataTable();
            Tarifler.Columns.Add("Tarif_ID", typeof(string));
            Tarifler.Columns.Add("Tarif_İsmi", typeof(string));
            Tarifler.Columns.Add("Talimatlar", typeof(string));

            DataTable TariflerveMalzemeler = new DataTable();
            TariflerveMalzemeler.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            TariflerveMalzemeler.Columns.Add("Tarif_ID", typeof(string));
            TariflerveMalzemeler.Columns.Add("Malzeme_ID", typeof(string));
            TariflerveMalzemeler.Columns.Add("Gram_mL", typeof(string));
            TariflerveMalzemeler.Columns.Add("Adet", typeof(string));

            DataTable Result = new DataTable();
            Result.Columns.Add("Tarif_İsmi", typeof(string));
            Result.Columns.Add("Malzeme_İsmi", typeof(string));
            Result.Columns.Add("Gram_mL", typeof(string));
            Result.Columns.Add("Adet", typeof(string));
            Result.Columns.Add("Talimatlar", typeof(string));

            var joins = from  tm in TariflerveMalzemeler.AsEnumerable()
                        join m in Malzemeler.AsEnumerable() on tm.Field<string>("Malzeme_ID") equals m.Field<string>("Malzeme_ID")
                        join t in Tarifler.AsEnumerable() on tm.Field<string>("Tarif_ID") equals t.Field<string>("Tarif_ID")
                        select new { tm = tm, m = m, t = t};
            foreach (var j in joins)
            {
                Result.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    j.t.Field<string>("Tarif_İsmi"),
                    j.m.Field<string>("Malzeme_İsmi"),
                    j.tm.Field<string>("Gram_mL"),
                    j.tm.Field<string>("Adet"),
                    j.t.Field<string>("Talimatlar")
                });
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry i'm really new to programming how should i use that code should i make a button and paste ur code into that or should i paste into to gridview ? and should i add Sqlcommand with my select line top of ur code ? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Easiest method is to fill the 3 tables using an adapter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)  Then make the DGV datasource the Results table.